# Is it ok to use let keyword as most of the old browsers don't have support of it?

Tags: browser, ecmascript-6, let

Actually let keyword is quite helpful but to use it there is danger that my application may get fail in old browsers, is there any solution?

Comment: If you have to contend with old browsers that don't support the let keyword, don't use it

Comment: Have you read about [BabelJS](https://babeljs.io/)?

Comment: Transpile your code to ES5 so you can write in ES6 with all the features, but transpile to ES5 for browser compatibility.

Comment: It means if I am developing modern application then I have to transpile the code to be assured that it work everywhere? Is it necessary? Won't it be a overhead?